# Preserving Comments after an Array

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

This is how my YAML looks like:

```
yaml_str = """\
steps:
  - init
  - run
  - cleanup

# This is a comment which needs to be preserved
"""
```

What I'd like to do is remove the first and the last items from `steps` while having the comments right after `cleanup` being kept. I.e. the output needs to be like this:

```
yaml_str = """\
steps:
  - run

# This is a comment which needs to be preserved
"""
```

How is this possible using ruamel.yaml?

P.S. As I understand, this is not quite the same case in terms of the API, as this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57585928/896276, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

OK, looks like I need to use this construct:

> parsed['steps'].ca.items[1] = parsed['steps'].ca.items.pop(2)

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Comments are associated with the item after which they follow and end-of-line comments are considered to be continued by empty lines and further comment-only lines. I would use `parsed['steps'].ca.items[-2] = parsed['steps'].ca.items.pop(-1)` to move the comment on the last item to the one before that though.

Comment: Thanks @Anthon. The only issue I'm facing now is an array with one element (one in the middle) being a mapping (others being just strings). Hope to resolve it as well. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When loading a data from a YAML file, `ruamel.yaml` normally attaches
comments to the latest collection being scanned, based on the key (in
case of a mapping) or the index (sequence).

So in your case the comment (and the empty end-of-line and empty line
before it) are attached to the sequence (and not the root level
mapping).

The comments are currently stored in an attribute `ca` (**c**omment **a**ttribute).
So for your example you can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
steps:
  - init
  - run
  - cleanup

# This is a comment which needs to be preserved
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
steps = data['steps']
del steps[0]
steps.pop(-1)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
steps:
  - run

# This is a comment which needs to be preserved
```

If you delete single items from a sequence the dictionary like object
(`CommentedSeq`) is smart enough to "move" the comment. (You can
insert `print(data['steps'].ca)` before and between deletes to see this
has occured).

This doesn't always work, and particularily not when the second element in your
sequence is a collection. In that case you need to move the comment yourself, to the last
element of that collection. If that item is a sequence/list, you can just move the comment
but if it is a mapping/dict, you need to rearrange things in order not to have
the comment appear between key and value:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
steps:
  - init
  - a: 42
    b: 39
  -   - 196
      - 3.0
  - cleanup

# This is a comment which needs to be preserved
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
steps = data['steps']

print(steps.ca)

del steps[2]  # you can comment this out to get the comment attached to 3.0

if isinstance(steps, list):
    if len(steps)-1 in steps.ca.items and len(steps) > 1 and isinstance(steps[-2], (list, dict)):
        # move the comment in advance
        tmp = steps[-2]
        ct = steps.ca.items.pop(len(steps)-1)
        if isinstance(tmp, list):
            key_tmp = len(tmp)-1
        else:
            key_tmp = list(tmp.keys())[-1]  # the final mapping key
            ct[0], ct[2] = None, ct[0]
        tmp.ca.items[key_tmp] = ct


del steps[0]
steps.pop(-1)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Comment(comment=None,
  items={3: [CommentToken('\n\n# This is a comment which needs to be preserved\n', line: 8, col: 0), None, None, None]})
steps:
  - a: 42
    b: 39

# This is a comment which needs to be preserved
```

Please pin your code on the ruamel.yaml version  you tested this with. These kind of internals can and will at 
some point change (hopefully with a proper API when they do).