# Is there a way to force ruamel insert a new (key:value) pair in an OrderedDict before the newline?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Having the following snippet, I'm trying to update each of the 3x ordereddict objects under 'a':

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import round_trip_load, round_trip_dump
s="""
a:
- b: c

- d: e
- f: g
"""
yaml_obj=round_trip_load(s)
yaml_sub_obj = [x for x in yaml_obj['a']]

for sub_obj in yaml_sub_obj:
    sub_obj.insert(1, "new_key", "new_value")
```

I was expecting the output below (empty line should be after last key-value pair of first sub-element), when using `round_trip_dump(yaml_obj, sys.stdout)`:

```
a:
- b: c
  new_key: new_value

- d: e
  new_key: new_value
- f: g
  new_key: new_value
```

However, dumping back the initial object with `round_trip_dump(yaml_obj, sys.stdout)` will display:

```
a:
- b: c

  new_key: new_value
- d: e
  new_key: new_value
- f: g
  new_key: new_value
```

2) Behavior for updating objects if keys are already present is ok, but I would like to not force the presence of this (key/empty_value) pair, because the YAMLs I'm processing are a little bit more complex and I want to fill them automatically:

```
s2="""
a:
 - b: c
   new_key:

 - c: d
   new_key:

 - e: f
   new_key:
"""
y = round_trip_load(s2)
for s in y["a"]:
     s["new_key"]="new_value"
```

Dumping it again looks fine:

```
a:
- b: c
  new_key: new_value

- c: d
  new_key: new_value

- e: f
  new_key: new_value
```

I saw this behavior on 0.16.5, but I upgraded ruamel.yaml to 0.16.10 and the behavior is the same. Is this the expected behavior if no `flow_style` is specified?

Comment: AFAICT `flow_style` even using the old style routines, doesn't influence this behaviour at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations are incorrect. As indicated in other locations (e.g.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57585928/1307905)) in ruamel.yaml comments
are associated with the previous nodes parsed and actually stored indexed by the
key of a mapping (or the index of a sequence).

And full line comments, and empty lines are currently handled as continuations of previous end-of-line-comments, whether
these EOL comments exist or not.

Apart of that you should be considering using the new API that has been around for a long time now, instead of the `round_trip_load`/`dump()` functions

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a:
- b: c

- d: e
- f: g
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for sub_obj in data['a']:
    index = 1
    new_key = "new_key"
    prev_key = list(sub_obj.keys())[index-1]
    sub_obj.insert(index, new_key, "new_value")
    try:
        sub_obj.ca.items[new_key] = sub_obj.ca.items.pop(prev_key)
    except KeyError:
        pass
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a:
- b: c
  new_key: new_value

- d: e
  new_key: new_value
- f: g
  new_key: new_value
```

If you have concrete end of line comment, then
you should not pop the `prev_key` but copy it and split its third element

```
import sys
from copy import deepcopy
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a:
- b: c  # some comment

# this is to make an emtpy line more clearly visible
- d: e
- f: g
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for sub_obj in data['a']:
    index = 1
    new_key = "new_key"
    prev_key = list(sub_obj.keys())[index-1]
    sub_obj.insert(index, new_key, "new_value")
    try:
        comment = sub_obj.ca.items[prev_key]
        new_comment = deepcopy(comment)
        comment[2].value, rest = comment[2].value.split('\n', 1)
        new_comment[2].value = '\n' + rest
        sub_obj.ca.items[new_key] = new_comment
    except KeyError:
        pass
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a:
- b: c  # some comment
  new_key: new_value

# this is to make an emtpy line more clearly visible
- d: e
  new_key: new_value
- f: g
  new_key: new_value
```

Be aware though that this is **not** a published API for handling comments, and can/will
change, so pin the version of ruamel.yaml that you use appropriately for your
project.

Comment: Thank you, Anthon! I upvoted your response. It solved that particular issue, which I tried to simplify as much as possible starting from the "real-life" issue I had. My yaml was more complicated, instead of "new_value", I have nested dictionaries(e.g.: "new_key" : {"new_dict_key":"new_dict_value"}
). Therefore, the empty line will be displayed after "new_key", but before"new_dict_key" and that's obviously expected: 
a:
- b: c  # some comment
  new_key:

# this is to make an empty line more clearly visible
    new_dict_key: new_dict_value

I'll try to dig more, using the new API. Thx!