# How do I update this yaml file with python and ruamel?

Tags: python, file, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a test.yaml file with content:

```
school_ids:
  school1: "001"

  #important school2
  school2: "002"


targets:
  neighborhood1:
    schools:
      - school1-paloalto
    teachers:
      - 33
  neighborhood2:
    schools:
      - school2-paloalto
    teachers:
      - 35
```

I want to use ruamel to update the file to look like this:

```
school_ids:
  school1: "001"

  #important school2
  school2: "002"

  school3: "003"


targets:
  neighborhood1:
    schools:
      - school1-paloalto
    teachers:
      - 33
  neighborhood2:
    schools:
      - school2-paloalto
    teachers:
      - 35
  neighborhood3:
    schools:
      - school3-paloalto
    teachers:
      - 31
```

How do I use ruamel to update the file to get the desired output by preserving the comments?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inp = open('/targets.yaml', 'r').read()

yaml = YAML()

code = yaml.load(inp)
account_ids = code['school_ids']
account_ids['new_school'] = "003"
#yaml.dump(account_ids, sys.stdout)


targets = code['targets']
new_target = dict(neighborhood3=dict(schools=["school3-paloalto"], teachers=["31"]))
yaml = YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=3, offset=2)
yaml.dump(new_target, sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just dumping `new_target` which you create from scratch not using the `code` or even `targets`.
Instead you should either use that `code` that
you loaded and extend the values associated with its root level keys and then dump `code`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inp = Path('test.yaml')

yaml = YAML()

code = yaml.load(inp)
school_ids = code['school_ids']
school_ids['school3'] = "003"


targets = code['targets']
targets['neighborhood3'] = dict(schools=["school3-paloalto"], teachers=["31"])
yaml = YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
school_ids:
  school1: '001'

  #important school2
  school2: '002'


  school3: '003'
targets:
  neighborhood1:
    schools:
      - school1-paloalto
    teachers:
      - 33
  neighborhood2:
    schools:
      - school2-paloalto
    teachers:
      - 35
  neighborhood3:
    schools:
      - school3-paloalto
    teachers:
      - '31'
```

Please note that your sequence indent needs to be at least 2 greater than your
offset (2 positions to have room for `-` + SPACE)

The output has the emtpy lines between after the key `school2`, as that is what
these are associated with during parsing. This can be moved to the new key, but
it is not trivial. If you need to do that (it is not important for the semantics
of the YAML document), then have a look at my answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57585928/1307905)

Comment: Thank you for your kind and prompt response @Anthon. I notice that in the example that I am following also in your response, we are printing in the sys.stdout. Is there a way to update the same file and write the updated fields and values into it? using the same ruamel module that is. Baically update the file... Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: @Becks If you are using a `pathlib.Path`  instance (as I do), writing back to file is as simple as doing `yaml.dump(code, inp)`. That appropriate opens, and closes, the file for you. Make a new `Path` if the output should go to a different file (or consider renaming `inp` if you need to preserve the old file contents)